# Getting an infinite loop with buddy system allocation malloc

Tags: c

I'm coding malloc in C with the buddy system allocation, and I can't figure out why I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop when I'm splitting memory.

Here's the relevant function:

```
void split_memory(int target_index, int current_index, metadata_t *current)
{

    if (target_index == current_index) return;
    current->size /= 2;

    // Create new half
    metadata_t *new = (metadata_t *) ((char *) current + current->size);
    new->size = current->size;
    new->in_use = 0;
    new->next = NULL;
    new->prev = NULL;

    // Move current out of the free list
    metadata_t* next = current->next;
    current->next = NULL;
    current->prev = NULL;
    if (next)
    {
        freelist[current_index] = next;
        next->prev = NULL;
    }

    // Move current into the lower freelist
    current->next = new;
    current->prev = NULL;
    new->next = NULL;
    new->prev = current;

    metadata_t* lower = freelist[current_index - 1];

    // If there are any blocks currently in lower, then make sure we add it to the end of the freelist
    if (lower)
    {
        while(lower->next)
        {
            lower = lower->next;
        }
        lower->next = current;
        current->prev = lower;
    }
    else
    {
        freelist[current_index - 1] = current;
    }

    split_memory(target_index, current_index - 1, current);
    split_memory(target_index, current_index - 1, new);
}
```

It looks like I'm accidently creating a circular linkedlist somehow and so the loop that hits the end of the freelist is never ending, but I can't figure out how I'm creating the circular linked list.

Comment: Looks like infinite recursion...

Comment: Please don't use a variable named `new` ... it makes me break out in hives!

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey Shouldn't be target_index is definitely smaller than current_index. Fairly sure it's a circular linked list.

Comment: @Eric Sorry! Will change it asap, it bugs me too :)

Comment: @Eric: I beg to differ. Using a variable named `new` is a great way to prevent subtle bugs from idiots trying to compile C with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @chintanparikh Just guessing what the problem is. You're right, `target_index` should equal `current_index` at some point to stop recursion.